# HTML Calculate button

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help explaining this code. I have changed the values but for some reason, the calculated value is always coming up as 12.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function display(x)
{
alert("The result is " + x);
}
function calculate(){
var values = new Array(5, 8, 18, 16);
var output = values[1]+values[3];
if (output >= 23){output = output / 2;}
else {output = output++;}
display(output);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="calculate()">Click to calculate</button>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yep. 8+16 is 24 so divided by 2 is 12 (arrays start at index `0` btw)

Comment: (8 + 16) / 2 _is_ 12.

Comment: Working as expected. `value[1]` (8) + `value[3]` (16) equals 24. Since it's above 23, it will divide by two, giving twelve. Could you clarify what's wrong?

Comment: How is 8 and 16 values 1 and 3? Since there is 4 values? Surely they are 2 and 4?

Comment: See Glen's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You may be thinking that using `values[1]` and `values[3]` will give you the first and third elements, specifically 5 and 18. However, the array index begins with 0. Changing your code to `values[0]` and `values[2]` would most likely give the desired result.